# Android Using Custom Appcompat Theme

Tags: android, xml, android-appcompat

Hi I created a custom theme using Android Action Bar Style Generator. I then imported all the resource files into my "res" folder. Then I changed my manifest file theme to use the newly created custom theme. However, when I view the app I do not see the style changes to my application. Basically where the default is blue, it should be red. Please help me figure out why this is not functioning properly. Thank you! I am not generating any errors, if that is important.

Manifest Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.homebrewedapps.unmfinder" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Unmfinderactionbar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the start of my style file:

```
<style name="Theme.Unmfinderactionbar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_unmfinderactionbar</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Unmfinderactionbar</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Unmfinderactionbar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Unmfinderactionbar</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Unmfinderactionbar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Unmfinderactionbar</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_unmfinderactionbar</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_unmfinderactionbar</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Unmfinderactionbar</item>        
</style>
```

Comment: Can you upload zip file in drive or dropbox that I can test on?